# No consigo recorrer elementos contiguos para verificar si el numero es primo o no, hasta ahora tengo esto:

Tags: python

Realizar una función que reciba un numero y devuelva una lista con los números primos que se pueden formar con dos dígitos contiguos.

```
Ej: Si recibe 21703
    21 No es primo
    17 Es primo 
    70 No es primo
    03 Es primo
La función devuelve [17,3]
```

Hasta ahora hice este código, me falta que recorra como lo pide aquí arriba.

```
  def esprimo(n):
    cont = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            cont = cont + 1
    if cont == 2:
        return True

def separar(n):
    l = []
    for elem in str(n):
        l.append(elem)
    q = []
    for elementos in l:
        q.append(int(elementos))
    return q
n = int(input("Numero:"))
print(separar(n))

def recorrer(n):
     x = separar(n)
     p = []
     for elem in x:
        if esprimo(elem):
            p.append(elem)
     return p
print(recorrer(n))
```

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta los detalles del error que obtienes. Como es python, verifica también las sangrías/indentations/"identaciones"

Comment: Gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Gonzalo, recuerda que si la respuesta soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta, puedes marcarla como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, disculpa usando tu lógica modifique la función separar con la cual agregas a la lista los valores siempre que tengan una longitud de 2, tal vez podría ayudarte

```
def separar(n):
    l = []
    new_value = ''
    for elem in str(n):
        last_value = new_value
        new_value = elem
        if len(last_value+''+new_value) == 2:
            l.append(last_value+''+new_value)
    q = []
    for elementos in l:
        q.append(int(elementos))
    return q
```

Comment: Mucha gracias, me sirvio.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo reducir tu codigo para lograr el resultado deseado usando [slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings_slicing.asp) para obtener cada par de numeros consecutivos y [list-comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) para mejorar la lectura del mismo.
He creado una funcion llamada `primos`, la cual retorna la lista con los numeros primos, utilizando la funcion `esprimo` que ya tenias.

```
def primos() -> list:
  numero = input('Numero:')
  pares_consecutivos = [numero[i: i+2] for i in range(len(numero)-1)]
  respuesta = [p for p in pares_consecutivos if esprimo(int(p))]
  return respuesta

primos()
```

##### Otra solucion interesante si estás usando python >= 3.10

El módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) a partir de Python 3.10 trae un metodo bastante interesante y que es perfecto para tu requerimiento, este metodo es [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise), el cual retorna una lista de tuplas con los pares consecutivos, por ejemplo:

```
print(list(itertools.pairwise('21703')))
```

Retornará: `[('2', '1'), ('1', '7'), ('7', '0'), ('0', '3')]`

Teniendo lo anterior en cuenta, otra solucion seria:

```
import itertools


def primos() -> list:
  numero = input('Numero:')
  pares_consecutivos = [''.join(t) for t in itertools.pairwise(numero)]
  respuesta = [p for p in pares_consecutivos if esprimo(int(p))]
  return respuesta

primos()
```

Salida de ambas alternativas: para `21703` es `['17', '03']`